# How to combine SimpleInjector for WCF and Web API

Tags: c#, wcf, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, simple-injector

I'm having a web project that hosts both WCF and Web API V2 ApiControllers.

Both should benefit from using SimpleInjector.

There are 2 different nuget packages for the 2 techniques:

- SimpleInjector.integration.WebApi
- SimpleInjector.Ingegration.Wcf

As in the given case registrations should be identical for both, what is the best way to approach this?
Should I create 2 different containers, since the scope will anyway be valid only as long as the requests are open?

I currently implemented the following, to use the correct ScopedLifestyles:

```
    public static void ConfigureForWCF(Container container)
    {
        container.Options.DefaultScopedLifestyle = new WcfOperationLifestyle();

        RegisterImplementations(container);
    }

    public static void ConfigureForWebAPI(Container container)
    {
        container.Options.DefaultScopedLifestyle = new WebApiRequestLifestyle();

        RegisterImplementations(container);
    }

    public static void RegisterImplementations(Container container)
    {
        // registrations for both WCF and Web API in here
        container.Register<IMyInterface, MyClass>();
```

and I know call them like that:

```
        // container for WCF
        var containerWCF = new Container();

        SimpleInjectorConfiguration.ConfigureForWCF(containerWCF);

        containerWCF.Verify();

        // use the container for WCF
        SimpleInjectorServiceHostFactory.SetContainer(containerWCF);



        // container for Web API
        var containerWebAPI = new Container();

        SimpleInjectorConfiguration.ConfigureForWebAPI(containerWebAPI);

        // this doesn't currently make sense for me as the controllers inheriting from ApiController get registered as Transient 
        //containerWebAPI.RegisterWebApiControllers(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
        // instead I will register the Controllers manually

        containerWebAPI.Verify();

        // use the container for Web API
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = new SimpleInjectorWebApiDependencyResolver(containerWebAPI);
```

Would it be possible to use the same Container eventually? 
(calling Verify on both containers also doesn't make sense as long as they have identical registrations)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've basically got 3 options:

1. Use two container instances
2. Use one container instance with a [hybrid lifestyle](https://simpleinjector.org/lifestyles#hybrid) that mixes the `WebApiRequestLifestyle` and `WcfOperationLifestyle`.
3. Use one container and use the same lifestyle for both WCF and Web API. This would typically be the `AsyncScopedLifestyle`.

Whether or not it is okay to have two containers depends on several values, such as the amount of services that should exist exactly once across the whole AppDomain. When you have 2 container instances, each get their own singleton instance, so you should provide each container with an existing instance. This can be troublesome, but in most cases it should not be a problem for a container to get its own singleton instance.

On the other side will having 2 containers mean that you will have to use some shared logic that can populate the registrations that both container instances share. This can complicate things.

On the other hand does having two containers allow both services to run in an isolated fashion, which can be beneficial.

If you choose to have one container instance, the use of a Hybrid lifestyle would be the most obvious solution, especially since the scoping technology used by WCF is different (based on `ThreadScopedLifestyle`) from the Web API scoping technology (which is based on `AsyncScopedLifestyle`). So, easiest solution is to register them as hybrid as follows:

```
container.Options.DefaultScopedLifestyle = Lifestyle.CreateHybrid(
    defaultLifestyle: new WebApiRequestLifestyle(),
    fallbackLifestyle: new WcfOperationLifestyle());
```

With this configuration, Simple Injector will use `WebApiRequestLifestyle` when there is an active Web API scope (which means a `AsyncScopedLifestyle` scope). In the absence of such scope, it will fallback to using the `WcfOperationLifestyle`.

This will be the easiest solution in case you wish to have one container.

The last option is to use one particular scoped lifestyle for both the WCF and the Web API application. Since Web API is inherently asynchronous, the only obvious lifestyle to use is `AsyncScopedLifestyle`. With ASP.NET Core we are actually moving away from custom framework-specific lifestyles and primarily use `AsyncScopedLifestyle` instead.

Although you can both use `AsyncScopedLifestyle` and `WebApiLifestyle` interchangeably in a Web API application, this doesn't hold for WCF. That's because the WCF integration package uses a technique that is similar to the `ThreadScopedLifestyle`, but uses its own implementation.

Although you can use the `AsyncScopedLifestyle` on single-threaded applications as well, you will have to replace part of the infrastructure for WCF that currently starts the WCF scope, to make it start an async Scope instead.

Since this is a bit more work to do, I would opt for either using 2 containers, or use the hybrid lifestyle.

Comment: Awesome answer. Thank you! Now I only have to figure out, why my ApiControllers are registered with a Transient scope by RegisterWebApiControllers. Since ApiController implements IDisposable, this doesn't seem to make sense.

Comment: Controllers are registered as transient, since this is the mpst convenient. They get disposed by Web API.

Comment: hmm, so how can container.Verify() now about this? 
it will return ...Controller  is registered as transient, but implements IDisposable.
sorry, it's off topic

Comment: Should not happen if you call RegisterWebApiControllers. That method suppresses that particular warning. You are doing something weird :)

Comment: :) thanks for the info. I run all the configurations in Application_Start of global.asax, first AutoMapper than the bunch of SimpleInjector commands above, and last i register the route for WebAPI. Will check it when I get some time.. thanks agaoin you provided great insights. Especially thanks for the work you put in SI!